# Connect timeout exception for AWS IOT

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, paho, aws-iot

AWSIoTPythonSDK.exception.AWSIoTExceptions.connectTimeoutException

I'm getting this exception after running the sample python code on my machine.

Referred to the github exmaple. https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python/issues/223

I tried node and python both the version of aws iot connection. Still unsuccesful

```
from AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib import AWSIoTMQTTClient

myMQTTClient = AWSIoTMQTTClient("random")


myMQTTClient.configureEndpoint("<sample>-ats.iot.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com", 8883)


myMQTTClient.configureCredentials("C:\\Users\\preetham\\Desktop\\awsiot\\root-CA.crt", "C:\\Users\\preetham\\Desktop\\awsiot\\SWM-Preetham.private.key", "C:\\Users\\preetham\\Desktop\\awsiot\\SWM-Preetham.cert.pem")


myMQTTClient.configureOfflinePublishQueueing(-1)  
myMQTTClient.configureDrainingFrequency(2)  
myMQTTClient.configureConnectDisconnectTimeout(10) 
myMQTTClient.configureMQTTOperationTimeout(5)  

myMQTTClient.connect()

while 1:
    myMQTTClient.publish("topic", "myPayload", 1)
```

can some one help me why this is happening?  We didn't face this anytime before. Little surprised on this.

Answer (score 6):

The sample created automatically associated a policy with some very specific restrictions, which actually blocked even the ThingShadowEcho sample to connect, by changing the policy to a very broad policy might be risky, but will get this exception solved.
First, go to aws console, find Secure/Policies, locate the specific policy for "Random", in that "Random-policy" choose edit policy document, put the following in there, and try again.

`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}`